# Ubuntu 14.04 (on linode) not doing "do-release-upgrade"

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I am getting this error and don't know how to approach the problem:

> After updating your package information, the essential package 
>   'ubuntu-minimal' could not be located. This may be because you have 
>   no official mirrors listed in your software sources, or because of 
>   excessive load on the mirror you are using. See /etc/apt/sources.list 
>   for the current list of configured software sources. 
>   In the case of an overloaded mirror, you may want to try the upgrade 
>   again later.

Can anyone please advise on what I need to do.

Comment: What does `apt-get update` do?  Do you get any errors?

Comment: See `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: There were no errors from apt-get update.

Answer (score 3):

I rebuilt my `/etc/apt/sources.list` with help from https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories. My sources.list had some of my custom ones and the Linode mirrors. I just replaced my sources.list with the output from https://repogen.simplylinux.ch. I ran the upgrade again and it succeeded.

**Example from my sources.list that failed**

```
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution. deb http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team. deb       
http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe deb   
http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
```

**Output from https://repogen.simplylinux.ch that worked**

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: I had the same error on **DigitalOcean** following the instructions on their official upgrade page to get from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-18-04. Changing the sources helped. Thx!